# Unable to start a mono-service2 daemon - missing method in "/usr/local/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll"

Tags: mono, mono-service

I'm writing a daemon in C# using mono. So far I managed to implement my logic and all and test it in a console program just fine. I'm using MonoDevelop 4.0.9 in Windows XP and compile it there and then move the files to a CentOS to test. I've compiled mono 3.0.12 on the CentOS manually and I can test my console program there without any problems. My project consists of several libraries (.net dll files) which contain my logic and I use the same files in two executable projects; the console and the daemon.

While the console runs smoothly, the daemon outputs the following error on start:

```
Missing method System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object,bool&) in assembly /usr/local/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /usr/bin/wssd/Base.dll
```

Which is strange since I compiled all my projects against `Mono / .Net 4.0`. Just to emphasis, both runs share the same list of library files, their only difference is the executable: `Console.exe` and `WSSDaemon.exe`.

And here's how I call both of them:

```
$ mono ./Console.exe
$ mono-service2 -d:$WORK_DIR -l:$PIDFILE -m:$SERVICE_NAME -n:$SERVICE_NAME $DAEMON --debug > /tmp/wssd_log.txt
```

And the wssd_log.txt is where I found the error message reported above. Can anyone give me a hint what would the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to find the problem, I had to use `mono-service` instead of `mono-service2`. It turned out that `mono-service2` is meant for .Net 2 and `mono-service` for .Net 4.5!! You can test this with the following command:

```
grep exec `type -p mono-service` | head -n 1
```

Which outputs:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe $args
```

while

```
grep exec `type -p mono-service2` | head -n 1
```

outputs:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS /usr/local/lib/mono/2.0/mono-service.exe $args
```

Anywho, I just hope others can benefit from my experience.